# Sein Kinofilm ist in Deutschland mit 1,3 Millionen Zuschauern sein kommerziell stärkster und auch im Ausland an der Kinokasse erfolgreich

Tags: sentence-structure

Why is the superlative adjective "stärkster" declined in this form?

Comment: How else would you decline it?

Comment: I just did not understand why stärkster ..... Now it is the omitted 'Kinofilm" would answer as Janka explained ....  thanks :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Sein Kinofilm ist in Deutschland mit 1,3 Millionen Zuschauern sein kommerziell stärkster und auch im Ausland an der Kinokasse erfolgreich.

This sentence has a lot of omitted parts. First the subject and predicate are left out in the second installment.

> Sein Kinofilm ist in Deutschland mit 1,3 Millionen Zuschauern sein kommerziell stärkster.
>
> Sein Kinofilm ist auch im Ausland an der Kinokasse erfolgreich.

Second, one *Kinofilm* is omitted in the first part.

> Sein Kinofilm ist **sein stärkster**.

*Sein stärkster* is a **Prädikativ**, a further description of the subject *sein Kinofilm*:

> Sein Kinofilm ist sein starker [Kinofilm].
>
> Sein Kinofilm ist sein stärkerer [Kinofilm].
>
> Sein Kinofilm ist sein stärkster [Kinofilm].

So, the reason why *stärkster* is declined that way is the omitted second *Kinofilm* in that sentence.

Some people enjoy writing down such *handgezwirbelte Sätze* but it's very frustrating for learners to add all the omitted words.